# Can instant oatmeal really expire?

Tags: food-safety

I ask because I ate a package of Quaker instant oatmeal (maple/brown sugar) at work today, it was just kinda a single package sitting in our "snack pantry". I looked for a date and it didn't have one. But I had forgotten breakfast and decided eh it should be ok.

So I made it, and while it tasted blandish, it didn't taste bad. It didn't smell bad it smelt like normal oatmeal.

However I looked at the Instant Oatmeal package and noticed the Quaker Copyright for 2012....so did I just eat 3 year old oatmeal? or just cause the copyright 2012 mark is on there (cause I know quaker is older than that) doesn't necessarily mean it was made in 2012.

That being said can instant oats really go bad anyways?

Thanks!

Comment: Short of weevils or other obvious contamination, darn-near forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A copyright date isn't a good way to determine the age of the food. It's likely that the copyright date is much older unless the design is very recent.

[As far as whether it goes bad, StillTasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17785) gives it 1 year past its date, unopened.

Comment: Are you saying the copyright data is older than the food? or vice versa?

Comment: Copyright older than food; I edited to clarify.

Comment: At least for Quaker, it probably is a decent estimate, actually - they change their labels fairly often, so I'd guess it's within a year or less.

Comment: @JoeM, perhaps, but I'd think that would apply more to the outer box (which the poster didn't have; it would have had the actual use/best by date), while the far more plain inner packages are probably updated far less frequently. Or maybe I just don't pay enough attention to them!